How to fix "AuthorizationHeaderMalformed when calling the Make Bucket operation" error in AWS s3 boto3
when i write this code it gives me this message, please help
aws s3 mb s3://hadsjkdshfjfdjhd
make_bucket failed: s3://hadsjkdshfjfdjhd An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The authorization header is malformed; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting "<YOUR-AKID>/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request".
Im trying to create a bucket using mb command

Please double check your credential file, and especially your aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. You may also need to provide your profile name in your command.
aws s3 mb s3://hadsjkdshfjfdjhd --profile [profile_name]

